# Where to put test-only migration scripts and how execute them?

Tags: testing, automated-tests, integration-testing, flyway

I have SQL scripts which populate tables with test data.

I want Flyway to execute them like that,

1. Executed during production run & test run

`src/main/resources/migration` contains `V1_0.sql`, `V2_0.sql`, etc.

2. Executed during test run only

`src/test/resources/migration` contains `V1_1-test-data.sql`, `V2_1-test-data.sql`, etc.

Is it possible to archive this with Flyway?

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Put the test data migration scripts in a separate folder and when you migrate to an environment that needs the test scripts use the [locations](https://documentation.red-gate.com/fd/locations-184127514.html) parameter to specify both folders (a comma separated list) rather than just the migrations folder, which you'd use for your production run.